# Angular - Data sometimes doesn't refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

while adding new employee data sometimes doesn't refresh, where is the problem? Maybe json server?
Here is github link https://github.com/Mateuszto/employeesApp

Commands to run app
json-server --watch src/server/db.json

ng serve

https://github.com/Mateuszto/employeesApp

Comment: Do you mean sometimes it adds and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Yea, u can see that when u copy my repo and try to add some users

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is updated but not displayed because you are not waiting for your `HTTP` request to be completed, *(because it's `async`)*. So your methods `sendCreateEmployeeAction`, `openSnackbar` and `dialogRef.close()` are all called before your employee is created:

So instead of the code below:

```
 createEmployee() {
    if(this.employeeForm.valid) {
      this.employeesService.createEmployee(this.employeeForm.value).subscribe();
      this.employeesService.sendCreateEmployeeAction();
      this.snackbarService.openSnackbar('Created successfully');
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }
```

Those three functions should be inside the `subscribe` function, **so your code will look something like this**:

```
createEmployee() {
    if (this.employeeForm.valid) {
      this.employeesService
        .createEmployee(this.employeeForm.value)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.employeesService.sendCreateEmployeeAction();
          this.snackbarService.openSnackbar('Created successfully');
          this.dialogRef.close();
        });
    }
  }
```

Which will make sure that they always run after your `HTTP` response completes. Also, you should handle the `error` case too. I only added the code for `successful`. response

Comment: You right sir, thank you a lot

Comment: @Mateuszto, if it works, can you mark it as selected answer to help others who come to this problem.